# I need a specification for .sxdata sections

Tags: links, documentation

Does a specification for .sxdata sections (in PE Objectfiles) exist?   I have read the Microsoft definition of PE files, and find the information on .sxdata section to be somewhat sparse.

My program reads object files, changes the code (in the .text sections) and writes a new object file.   I need to do the "right thing" with .sxdata sections.  To do that I think I need to know more about the .sxdata sections.  I need to parse and generate correctly which requires the form, but I want them also to behave correctly, which implies understanding how they are used.  (Or whether they are used and by what)

If no more complete definition exists, does somebody know of some source code I could analyze to figure out how they work?